# How do I determine rowsAffected array elements in a T-SQL query?

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which I execute to insert data from NodeJs which returns a value as the `rowsAffected`. The `rowsAffected` is an array in this case of 3, is there anywhere some docs to determine the logic of the this array?

I am trying to determine the rows updated, my best guess would be the 2nd element in array , 1st one being the `NewID()`, 2nd the actual Insert and 3rd `SELECT @guid`, am I correct or am I missing something?

```
Create PROCEDURE sp_FarmFollowUp_INS
    (@p_notes_guid     VARCHAR(50),
     @p_property_guid  VARCHAR(50),
     @p_contact_name   VARCHAR(150),
     @p_contact_date   DATETIME,
     @p_contact_type   VARCHAR(50),
     @p_contact_email  VARCHAR(250),
     @p_contact_phone  VARCHAR(20),
     @p_contact_reason VARCHAR(50),
     @p_notes          VARCHAR(1000),
     @p_created_by     VARCHAR(50))
AS

declare @guid Varchar(50)
set @guid  = NEWID()

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_FarmFollowUp    (
    guid,
    notes_guid,
    property_guid,
    contact_name,
    contact_date,
    contact_type,
    contact_email,
    contact_phone,
    contact_reason,
    notes,
    created_by,
    created_on)
VALUES  
(
    @guid,
    @p_notes_guid,
    @p_property_guid,
    @p_contact_name,
    @p_contact_date,
    @p_contact_type,
    @p_contact_email,
    @p_contact_phone,
    @p_contact_reason,
    @p_notes,
    @p_created_by,
    getDate()
)

SELECT @guid as FollowUpiId
```

So this returns me the following result

```
{ recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
recordset: [ { FollowUpiId: '2839D43D-CF9E-466D-B512-1DCD73833380' } ],
output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 1, 1, 1 ],
returnValue: 0 }
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @MisterniceGuy - That stored proc, as it's current written, is only able to insert (not update) a single row per execution. Also +100 on the "don't use the sp_ prefic on procedures".

Answer (score 1):

You have three separate queries in your stored procedure - one to set the GUID (one row affected), the INSERT (one row affected), and the SELECT to return the GUID (one row affected). Thus, you have three 'Rows Affected' values.

If you wish to shut off that array, add:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

as the first line of your stored procedure.

Comment: I still want to get my rowsaffected for Insert so I guess the 2 Nd nbr in array is what i need to check. I assume I can not turn of count for parts of stored procedure

Comment: You can, by issuing a `SET NOCOUNT ON` immediately prior to the SQL statement you want the count on, and a `SET NOCOUNT OFF` immediately after it.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to note is that if your SQL statement initiates a trigger, the triggered update counts will be included as additional indexes in the rowsAffected array.

I just ran into this today, and it took me a minute to figure out what was happening. I didn't see any notes about this in the documentation.